# Material UI Grid Fluid Width with Fixed Width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

This is the Grid I have:

```
 <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        item 1
      </Grid>
      <Grid item style={{ width: "100px" }}>
        item 2
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        item 3
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

How can I make it so item 2 is fixed with to 100px and item 1 and 3 are taking the rest of the space half and half. In CSS, I can do it by giving Item2 `width:100px`and Item1 and Item3 `calc( 50% - 50px )` but, I don't want to take this approach because mine as well I could do straight CSS without involving Grid.

Comment: Have you tried xs='auto' for the outer 2 Grid items? I'm not sure it will give you what you want, but worth a try. Otherwise, you may be better off using div's.

Comment: yep that's what I did.